# Is there a per-request limit for simultaneous transactions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using a lot of (sharded) counters in my application. According to my current design, a single request can cause 100-200 of different counters to increment.

So for each counter I'm picking up one shard whose value I'm incrementing. I'm incrementing each shard in a transaction, which means I will end up doing 100-200 transactions as part of processing a single request. Naturally I intend to do this asynchronously, so that I will be essentially running all 100-200 transactions in parallel.

As this number feels pretty high, I'm left wondering whether there is some per-request or per-instance limit for the amount of simultaneous transactions (or datastore requests). I could not find information on this from the documentation.

By the way for some reason Google's documentation states that "if your app has counters that are updated frequently, you should not increment them transactionally" [1], but on the other hand their code example on sharding counters uses a transaction for incrementing the shard [2]. I have figured I can use transactions if I just use enough shards. I prefer transactions as I would like my counters not to miss increments.

1. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Answer (score 2):

There are three limitations that will probably cause you problems here:

- 1/sec write limit per entity group
- 5 entity groups per XG
- **10 concurrent 'threads' per instance**

The last one is the tricky one for your use case.

Its a bit hard to find info on (and may in fact be out of date information - so its worth testing), but each instance only allows 10 concurrent core threads (regardless of size - F1/F2/F...).

That is, ignoring the creation of background threads, if you were to assume that each request takes a thread, as does each RPC (datastore, memcache, text search etc), you can only use 10 at a time. If the scheduler thinks an incoming request would exceed 10, it will route the request to a new instance.

In a scenario you want to write to 100 entities in parallel, i'd expect it to only allow about 10 concurrent writes (the rest blocking), but also your instance could only service one request at a time.

Alternatives for you:

- Use dedicated memcache - you'll need to handle backing the counters onto durable storage but you could do that in batches on a backend. This may result in you losing some data due to flushes, whether thats ok or not you'll have to decide
- Use CloudSQL sequences or tables - if you dont require huge scale,
  but do require lots of counters, this may be a good approach - you
  could store counts as raw counts, or as timeseries data and
  post-process for accurate counts
- Use pull queues to update counters in batches on a backend. You can process many 'events' across your many counter tables in larger batches. The downside is that the counts will not be up to date at any given point in time

The best approach is probably a hybrid.

For example, accepting some eventual consistency in counts:

- When a request comes in - atomic increment of counters in memcache
- When a request comes in - queue an 'event' task
- Serve needed counts from memcache - if not present load from the datastore
- Use TTLs on memcache, so that eventually the datastore is seen as the 'source of truth'
- Run a cron which pulls 100 'event' tasks off the queue every 5 minutes (or as appropriate), and updates counters for all the events in a transaction in the datastore

UPDATE: I found this section in the docs, [talking about controlling max number of concurrent requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#automatic_scaling_1), it makes a nebulous reference to

> You may experience increased API latency if this setting is too high.

I'd say it's worth playing with.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not realize that the limit on concurrent requests per instance is in practice also a limit for concurrent threads per instance. This does not seem to be documented clearly anywhere, but it still seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using a sharded counter approach to avoid contention, as described in: [cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Can you collect all your counters in a single entity, so that each shard is a bunch of counters? Then you wouldn't need so many separate transactions. According to [cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#quotas), an entity can be 1MB max, and certainly 200 integers will fit into that size restriction just fine.

It may be that you don't know the property names in advance.  Here is an approach expressed in Go using its PropertyLoadSaver interface that can deal with dynamic counter names.

```
const (
    counterPrefix = "COUNTER:"
)

type shard struct {
    // We manage the saving and loading of counters explicitly.
    counters map[string]int64 `datastore:"-"`
}

// NewShard construct a new shard.
func NewShard() *shard {
    return &shard{make(map[string]int64)}
}

// Save implements PropertyLoadSaver.
func (s *shard) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    for key, value := range s.counters {
        c <- datastore.Property{
            Name:  counterPrefix + key,
            Value: value,
            NoIndex: true,
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Load implements PropertyLoadSaver.
func (s *shard) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    s.counters = make(map[string]int64)
    for prop := range c {
        if strings.HasPrefix(prop.Name, counterPrefix) {
            s.counters[prop.Name[len(counterPrefix):]] = prop.Value.(int64)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The key is to use the raw API for defining your own property names when saving to the datastore.  The Java API almost certainly has similar access, given the existence of [PropertyContainer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer).

And the rest of the code in described in the [sharding article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) would be expressed in terms of manipulating a single entity that knows about mutiple counters.  So, for example, rather than having `Increment()` deal with a single counter:

```
// // Increment increments the named counter.
func Increment(c appengine.Context, name string) error {
    ...
}
```

we'd change its signature to a bulk-oriented operation:

```
// // Increment increments the named counters.
func Increment(c appengine.Context, names []string) error {
    ...
}
```

and the implementation would find a single shard, call `Increment()` for each of the counters we'd want to increment, and `Save()` that single entity to the datastore, all within a single transaction.  `Query` would also involve consulting all the shards... but reads are fast.  We still maintain the sharding architecture to avoid write contention.

---

The complete example code for Go is:

```
package sharded_counter

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strings"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"
)

const (
    numShards     = 20
    shardKind     = "CounterShard"
    counterPrefix = "counter:"
)

type shard struct {
    // We manage the saving and loading of counters explicitly.
    counters map[string]int64 `datastore:"-"`
}

// NewShard constructs a new shard.
func NewShard() *shard {
    return &shard{make(map[string]int64)}
}

// Returns a list of the names stored in the shard.
func (s *shard) Names() []string {
    names := make([]string, 0, len(s.counters))
    for name, _ := range s.counters {
        names = append(names, name)
    }
    return names
}

// Lookup finds the counter's value.
func (s *shard) Lookup(name string) int64 {
    return s.counters[name]
}

// Increment adds to the counter's value.
func (s *shard) Increment(name string) {
    s.counters[name]++
}

// Save implements PropertyLoadSaver.
func (s *shard) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    for key, value := range s.counters {
        c <- datastore.Property{
            Name:    counterPrefix + key,
            Value:   value,
            NoIndex: true,
        }
    }
    close(c)
    return nil
}

// Load implements PropertyLoadSaver.
func (s *shard) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    s.counters = make(map[string]int64)
    for prop := range c {
        if strings.HasPrefix(prop.Name, counterPrefix) {
            s.counters[prop.Name[len(counterPrefix):]] = prop.Value.(int64)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// AllCounters returns all counters.
func AllCounters(c appengine.Context) (map[string]int64, error) {
    var results map[string]int64
    results = make(map[string]int64)
    q := datastore.NewQuery(shardKind)
    q = q.Ancestor(ancestorKey(c))
    for t := q.Run(c); ; {
        var s shard
        _, err := t.Next(&s)
        if err == datastore.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return results, err
        }
        for _, name := range s.Names() {
            results[name] += s.Lookup(name)
        }
    }
    return results, nil
}

// ancestorKey returns an key that all counter shards inherit.
func ancestorKey(c appengine.Context) *datastore.Key {
    return datastore.NewKey(c, "CountersAncestor", "CountersAncestor", 0, nil)
}

// Increment increments the named counters.
func Increment(c appengine.Context, names []string) error {
    shardName := fmt.Sprintf("shard%d", rand.Intn(numShards))
    err := datastore.RunInTransaction(c, func(c appengine.Context) error {
        key := datastore.NewKey(c, shardKind, shardName, 0, ancestorKey(c))
        s := NewShard()
        err := datastore.Get(c, key, s)
        // A missing entity and a present entity will both work.
        if err != nil && err != datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
            return err
        }
        for _, name := range names {
            s.Increment(name)
        }
        _, err = datastore.Put(c, key, s)
        return err
    }, nil)
    return err
}
```

which, if you look closely, is pretty much the example with a single, unnamed counter, but extended to handle multiple counter names.  I changed a little bit on the query side so that the reads are using the same ancestor key so that we're in the same entity group.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This approach also came in my mind and I'm still considering it. There is a however a much larger pool of counters from which the 100-200 counters to increment are picked. I would need to group counters in categories that are usually incremented at the same time. While it complicates the code, this is starting to feel like the correct way to do this.

Comment: Yeah; I think you may want to rethink the original approach.  I don't think the design in the Sharding article we've been quoting was intended to be used for bulk update of a large number of counters.  Even with parallelism, 100-200 separate writes per request sounds expensive and fraught with write contention.  Of course, my intuition may be leading me astray here.  Profiling may help.

Comment: Just to reiterate: I think the key thing here is to *batch* the interaction with the datastore.   The design in my answer tries to batch the counters into a single entity.  But you might be able to get similar results by batch retrieval of all the shards that are involved, mutating them, and then batch saving all those shards back, all in one single transaction.  See the "High Performance Apps with Go on App Engine" talk: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/333519914?_ga=1.267120011.400147855.1413824588; the concepts of batching in that talk should apply to all the languages.

Comment: To do proper profiling of the RPCs, you can look into Appstats: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Comment: dyoo, doing a batch fetch and save within a transaction would require me to place shards of different counters in the same entity group (or a few of them, to be precise). In that sense it is pretty similar to the solution previously discussed. ANYWAY, I have now already implemented the previously discussed solution. I don't think that write contention would be a problem with the separate writes though.

Comment: By the way: As I have found an acceptable solution to my problem, I could mark the question as answered. However I'm not sure whether I should do it, as there is no answer to the original question on the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses! I think I now have the answers I need.

### Regarding the per-request or per-instance limit

There is per-instance limit for concurrent threads, which effectively limits the amount of concurrent transactions. The default limit is 10. It can be incremented, but it is unclear what side-effects that will have.

### Regarding the underlying problem

I chose to divide the counters in groups in such a way that counters that are usually incremented "together" are in the same group. Shards carry partial counts for all counters within the group the individual shard is associated with.

Counts are incremented still in transactions, but due to grouping only a maximum of five transactions per request is needed. Each transaction increments numerous partial counts stored in a single shard, which is represented as a single datastore entity.

Even if the transactions are run in series, the time to process a request will still be acceptable. Each counter group has a few hundred counters. I make sure there are enough shards to avoid contention.

**It should be noted that this solution is only possible because the counters can be divided into fairly large groups of counters that are typically incremented together.**